# How to make @UiField fields private

Tags: java, gwt, sonarqube, visibility

Sonar complains about the following line:

```
@UiField
Button saveBtn;
```

> Variable 'saveBtn' must be private and have accessor methods.

Howerver when I set the visibility modifier to `private`, IntelliJ IDEA complains:

> @UiField 'saveBtn' should not be' private'

What is the best solution about this conflict (besides disabling this sonar warning)?

Comment: Disabling the Sonar warning. Or not using the UIBinder framework.

Answer (score 2):

The code generation of GWT requires that the `@UiFields` are not private. The UIBinder code generator, that is run during compilation, will create a lot of Java code for you that is added dynamically to your project.

This code will directly access the fields and bind the widgets to your variables. This generated code is not using any accessors and there is no option to allow this. (and actually, that makes perfect sense, as it disguises the fact, that these variables are actually set and makes the semantics of the annotation clear).

That is the rationale behind the requirement, that these fields are not allowed to be private. Thus, there is no way around this but to disable the sonar warning for the class.

Comment: If suitable, you can disable the rule only for a relevant set of classes - see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Answer (score 1):

For UiBinder (and many other features of GWT, like i18n, ClientBundles, etc.), the GWT compiler generates an additional Java class in the same package as the view. This class has to access the view's fields (for example, to instantiate them), so they need to be package visible (also known as default). `private` does not satisfy this requirement.

Let's see this on an example:

We have `ApplicationView.java` in some package:

```
public class ApplicationView extends Composite {
    /* Needs to be package visible too */
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, ApplicationView> {
    }

    /* Doesn't matter what modifiers are here, but 
       it's usually static to give a hint to the GWT compiler
       that this field can be shared between instances of
       this class (like a, well, static)
    */
    private static Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField Button button;

    public ApplicationView() {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

In the same package you have `ApplicationView.ui.xml` which defines how your view is laid out.

What you usually don't see is that the GWT compiler generates an additional Java class for every UiBinder view. In this case, it'd be `ApplicationView_BinderImpl.java`, in the same package, but in a different source folder. It depends on what you use to build your project, but in case of a maven project I've based this on, it was in `target/.generated`.

In a very abbreviated form, `ApplicationView_BinderImpl` might look like this:

```
public class ApplicationView_BinderImpl implements UiBinder<com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget, com.example.ApplicationView>, com.example.ApplicationView.Binder {

  public com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget createAndBindUi(final com.example.ApplicationView owner) {
    return new Widgets(owner).some_generated_method();
  }
}
```

As you can see, this class implements the `Binder` interface you defined in your view. When you call `createAndBindUi` from your view, you pass the instance of your view to this method - this is so that this method can instantiate all the `@UiField`s, etc. If those fields were private, this class wouldn't be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

you can't make these fields to be private,It better you modify sonar rules in this case...